# Выгрузка Google таблицы

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

Использую таблицу в качестве БД.
Не могу понять каким образом я могу выгрузить таблицу в .json файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, самое простое, это

- Экспортировать лист в CSV с помощью Google Sheets API / Drive API
- Преобразовать данные из CSV в JSON c помощью [tablib](https://pypi.org/project/tablib/0.9.3/)

[Пример](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/webapp-spreadsheet_to_json) на Google Apps Script. Там создается сервис, который преобразует нужную Таблицу в JSON. При вызове сервиса вы сразу получаете результат.